# pentaho report page numbering with page breaks

Tags: report, pentaho, page-break

I have been trying to display page numbers by breaking the pages in the last 2 hours which must take no more than 2 minutes. Actually I am able to  display 1/1 at the very bottom of the report but the report is very long and I want to display it with page breaks. What I have tried is:

1. created a function called "page of pages" and then dragged this to
   page footer.. this way displays 1/1 at the very bottom of the report
2. Selected the 'master report' in structure set the 'pagebreak-after'
   and 'pagebreak-before' to true. does not work.
3. set the "common->value" as =VALUE([PageOfPagesFunction3]) ...
   (PageOfPagesFunction3 is my function created to display page
   numbers..) does not work.

Is there any other way I can try? I could not find any other example on the net..
maybe apart from these ones I am missing a step to get it work.

Any help is appreciated..

Thanks in advance.

Oz...

Comment: my question starts with "Hi everyone," but it does not display my edit.. just manners but matters sometimes..

Answer (score 1):

there is one function(in summary) called **page of pages**.
use this function in report footer section.